'Merge3' requires that 'Binding<Double>' conform to 'Publisher'
Minimal Code Used
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value1: Double = 0
    @State private var value2: Double = 0
    @State private var value3: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Your Test UI
        }
        .onReceive(calculateOnChange()) { _ in
            // ...
        }
    }

    private func calculateOnChange() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge3($value1, $value2, $value3)
           .map { _ in () }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

The error is
Generic struct 'Merge3' requires that 'Binding' conform to 'Publisher'
I don't understand why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated

$ on a @State gives you a Binding, not a Publisher. You may be confusing this with using $ on a @Published, which does give you a Publisher. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use Publishers here -- you can just use onChange instead of your onReceive.

My app is using @State to hold values in a form. One field is calculated based on the values. Imagine having a calculator with 2 textfield and when you change the field, the result should be calculated (without tapping any additional controls). Can I use @Published instead of @State?

@Published is for use inside an ObservableObject. You can move your state inside one of those, but there doesn't seem to be any need to do that -- you can just use onChange with your current @State variables.

That being said, if you make whatever the result of calculateOnChange is a computed property, you wouldn't need to do any of that -- it would automatically work. That's probably the right way unless calculateOnChange() is very heavy on performance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75069760/is-it-possible-to-update-a-view-based-of-two-values-with-the-task-modifier/75070287#75070287

Let's find out what type $value1 is:
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value1: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Your Test UI
        }
    }

    func printType() {
        print("The type is \(type(of: $value1))")
    }
}

let content = ContentView()
content.printType()

Running this yields
The type is Binding<Double>
So $value1 is not a Publisher, it's a Binding.
If you want to do something similar with publishers you could write it like this:
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value1 = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(0)
    @State var value2 = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(0)
    @State var value3 = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(0)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .onReceive(calculateOnChange()) { value in
            print("The new value is \(value) ")
        }
    }

    private func calculateOnChange() -> AnyPublisher<Double, Never> {
        Publishers.Merge3(value1, value2, value3)
            .map { value in
                return value
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

let view = ContentView()
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = NSHostingView(rootView: view)

view.value1.value = 3
view.value2.value = 4
view.value3.value = 5


State should always be private https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

In production code I would tend to agree with you. The state in this code is not private for the sake of illustration via the playground.  Using absolutes like "always" lead to statements that are rarely true.

Wouldn’t it be better to just illustrate with code that doesn’t go against the documentation?

No, because making the state properties private confuses the issue unnecessarily.  In answering the question the goal is clarity over correctness.
